# Acrobat forms and javascript calculation

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

In a form I have **4 radio buttons**, under the label `Q3`. Also i have a text field labeled `lictype` Each radio button has its own respective `Button Radio Choice Value`

- radio1 = `Pre`
- radio2 = `Pro`
- radio3 = `Ult`
- radio4 = `Uns`

When a radio button is checked. I want the value of that button to be displayed in the `lictype` text field.

Here is the JS I tried in a calculation.

```
var q3 = this.getField("value")

if (q3.value == "Pre”){
{
lictype.value = “Pre";
}
elseif (q3.value == "Pro”)
{
lictype.value = “Pro";
}
elseif (q3.value == "Ult”)
{
lictype.value = “Ult";
}
else (q3.value == "Uns”)
{
lictype.value = “Uns";
}
```

[image: VISUAL DESCRIPTION]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested: I was able to accomplish this by using `JS` to do a SHOW/HIDE on elements in the ACROBAT properties menu.

1. Set a different text field for each of the radio buttons
2. Set the property of each radio button to `SHOW` and then `HIDE` the appropriate text field.

In the the text field: Stack all of them in the desired location and set each `default value` in the properties panel to their respective value names.

Problem solved!